# Give focus to Navigation Panel in Foxit Reader with keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, foxit-reader, navigation, keyboard-navigation

Is there a way to give focus to the navigation side panel in Foxit (Reader 7.2.8 / Windows 8) using keyboard shortcuts only?

I navigate my desktop almost exclusively with the keyboard and reference a lot of pdf books. I would like it if I could give focus to the navigation side panel (mainly the bookmarks view) so that I can select a chapter but I cannot find if this is possible. Seems strange considering you can do almost everything else from the keyboard so I'm wondering if I'm missing something.

I know that you can open/close the side panel using ctrl+h or F4 but that does not give focus so that I can make a selection. I also know that ctrl+tab from within the sidebar will start cycling through the open documents but will not return to the nav bar when the cycle completes (a very poor design decision IMHO).

My current workaround is ctrl+b > Enter > Del (to create new bookmark, save it, then delete it) but this is obnoxious because its 2x as many keystrokes that I need to normally do a task like this and I have to confirm/deny the doc edits when I close.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Like you, I navigate as much as possible by keyboard and use bookmarks to maneuver through PDFs, so I've also searched for this answer. However, in thoroughly searching the forums on the Foxit site and experimenting with different keyboard possibilities, I've never found a way to do what you want.

**A couple further workarounds that might help a little** (but that you probably already know):

1. After *ctrl+b*, use *ctrl+z* instead of *enter > del* to save 1 keystroke (still asks if you want to save doc though).
2. Leave the bookmarks panel open and close nav panel with F4. It will save this view even if you close and reopen the document. (Makes sure "Restore last view settings when reopening" in File > Preferences > History is checked.)

Other than that, putting a request for this feature might be your best bet.